# What command does Unity use to launch a program

Tags: unity, ibm-lotus-notes

For work I need to use the IBM Lotus Notes e-mail client. I have installed it without much problem, but I'm having troubles in launching it when I start the pc. The problem is that I can't find how I can launch the client from the terminal, so I can't put it in the startup list.

As of right now, I start the client by searching in my Unity for 'Notes' and this brings up the client and I just press enter to start running it. Is there a way I can figure out which command Unity uses to start the client so I can add it to the startup list?

Comment: ehm, According to https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Various_ways_to_launch_Notes_client#Linux the command IS actually "notes" ;-)

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Will try the provided solutions

Comment: Lotus Notes; my commiserations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `/usr/share/applications` there will be a `.desktop` file for the app. This may not have the most obvious name, but you will be able to figure it out by trial and error...

Open the `.desktop` file and look for the **first** line that starts with

```
Exec=
```

After `=` is the command the launcher uses to start the program, so you can use it in a terminal.

You may be able to simplify the command, for example, if it is a path, but the application is in your path, you can type only the name of the application. Or, your system might even have a shortcut to it.

**Examples**

In `libreoffice-calc.desktop` I find the line

```
Exec=libreoffice --calc
```

Typing `libreoffice --calc` launches libreoffice calc

In `python2.7.desktop` I find

```
Exec=/usr/bin/python2.7
```

But I can launch it with only `python` because:

```
$ file $(which python)
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to python2.7
```

In the file `telegram.desktop` I find

```
Exec=/opt/telegram/Telegram
```

But I can launch it only with `Telegram` because I have added `/opt/telegram` to my path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/telegram:/opt/lks-indicator:/snap/bin
```

(See how to add directories to your path [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path))

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way I can figure out which command Unity uses to start the client so I can add it to the startup list?

Yes, the command is inside a `.desktop` file. See `/usr/share/applications/` for a lot of them. It probably will be named `notes.desktop`.

Do a

```
sudo updatedb
locate notes.desktop
```

or if that shows nothing use

```
locate *.desktop | more
```

and scan for a possible desktop file that looks like notes.

Then do a `more notes.desktop` and look for the executable (`Exec=`).

---

But I would have guessed that the command is actually `notes` first. The dash will show you the actual command name.

Comment: Wasn't notes. It turns out that it is /opt/ibm/notes/framework/../notes %F

Comment: Yes then the command IS notes. What you are missing: that dir is not in your PATH. Add `/opt/ibm/notes/frame‌​work/../` (so everything before "notes") to your path and you can type just "notes" from command line.

Comment: You're right! I misread it because I got confused with notes-app from Ubuntu.. My bad

Comment: Actually, you can normalize that path by dropping the `..` and the preceding directory.  So all you need is `/opt/ibm/notes` in your path.